# Supplied equations not differential or integral equations of the given functions

Tags: differential-equations, syntax

I am trying to solve this differential equations and I have 2 initial conditions. However, mathematica doesn't seem to work.  I get `Solve::ifun` and `DSolve::bvfail` warning messages. Please help. Thank you.

`DSolve[{k Sin[θ[t]]==θ''[t],θ[0]==θ0,θ'[0]==w0},θ[t],t]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the general solution:

```
dsol = DSolve[{k Sin[θ[t]] == θ''[t]}, θ, t]
```

The resulting equations for the initial condition cannot be solved symbolically.

```
ics = {θ[0] == θ0, θ'[0] == w0} /. dsol;
Solve[#, {C[1], C[2]}] & /@ ics
```

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

[image]

Comment: If i do this in the solution there will be c1 and c2, is there any \way to get rid of those constants and express them in terms of the initial conditions instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "set up"? I have tried to use parametricNDSolve but that only gives me the graph and not the function. Is there anyway to obtain the function? Thank you

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. {{},{}} is the output

Comment: @Bob, Oops, I forgot to remove the `[t]` from theta in the second argument to `DSolve`.  Usually one wants the pure function.

Comment: @Bob You can solve any of the equations in `ics` for `C[2]` using `Solve`, but it won't solve for `C[1]`.